# Is there more elegant way to traverse data by batch in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to achieve my own data loader in python. The target is to **randomly traverse dataset by mini-batch, and I wonder if there is a more elegant way to achieve it**.

For example, I have a dataset `dataset=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. When `batch_size=3`, the returned three batches should be like: `[1,5,7],[2,3,4],[6,8,9]`. Here is my achievement:

```
import numpy as np

class DataLoader:
    def __init__(self, data: list, batch_size: int):
        self.data = data
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.samples_reserve = None

    def _reset(self):
        self.samples_reserve = np.arange(len(self.data)).tolist()

    def __iter__(self):
        self._reset()
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if len(self.samples_reserve) == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        samples_choice = set(np.random.choice(self.samples_reserve, self.batch_size, replace=False))
        self.samples_reserve = list(set(self.samples_reserve) - samples_choice)
        return list(samples_choice)

    def __len__(self):
        return int(len(self.data) / self.batch_size)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in DataLoader([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3):
        print(i)
```

The `__next__` function must maintain the current reserved data by transfer data between `set` and `list`. I wonder if I can achieve the following code in a more elegant way, e.g. are there some api functions that I can use directly, e.g. sample?

```
    samples_choice = set(np.random.choice(self.samples_reserve, self.batch_size, replace=False))
    self.samples_reserve = list(set(self.samples_reserve) - samples_choice)
```

Comment: It would be easier to shuffle your initial dataset, then just peel off the items in order.  Shuffling is easy.  If there are N items, then loop N times, swapping item N for a random item.

Comment: Or equivalently, shuffle the indices `np.arange(len(dataset))`. Then you don't need to load the entire dataset into memory.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, based on [`numpy.random.Generator.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice):

```py
def get_samples(dataset, size):
    if not dataset:
        return []
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    if size >= len(dataset):
        size = len(dataset)
    sd = set(dataset)
    samples = []
    while sd:
        sample = rng.choice(list(sd), min(size, len(sd)), replace=False)
        samples.append(list(sample))
        sd -= set(sample)
    return samples

print(get_samples(list(range(20)), 7))
```